# Вывод значение radiobox которое привязано к кнопке

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Как реализовать одну единую функцию вывода `id` `radiobutton`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class App(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Тест'
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.radio_box_1 = QRadioButton('1', self)
        self.radio_box_2 = QRadioButton('2', self)
        button = QPushButton()
        button.setText('Вывод')
        button.clicked.connect(self.print_names)
        layout.addWidget(self.radio_box_1)
        layout.addWidget(self.radio_box_2)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.button_group = QButtonGroup()
        self.button_group.addButton(self.radio_box_1, 1)
        self.button_group.addButton(self.radio_box_2, 2)
        self.button_group.buttonClicked.connect(lambda:  a.clear())
        self.button_group.buttonClicked.connect(lambda number_id: a.append(self.button_group.id(number_id)))

    def print_names(self):
        print(a)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = []
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Мне надо, чтобы в функции `self.button_group.buttonClicked` не было бы `lambda` и все было бы написано в одной функции(как я думаю это по логике так и надо а не писать 2 `lambda`) , если такое возможно не могли бы привести пример как это реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование [`checkedId`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#checkedId) в данном случае заменяет метод

`lambda number_id: a.append(self.button_group.id(number_id))`

и помогает объеденить эти действия в одну функцию

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class App(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Тест'
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.radio_box_1 = QRadioButton('1', self)
        self.radio_box_2 = QRadioButton('2', self)
        button = QPushButton()
        button.setText('Вывод')
        button.clicked.connect(self.print_names)
        layout.addWidget(self.radio_box_1)
        layout.addWidget(self.radio_box_2)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.button_group = QButtonGroup()
        self.button_group.addButton(self.radio_box_1, 1)
        self.button_group.addButton(self.radio_box_2, 2)

    def print_names(self):
        a = self.button_group.checkedId()
        print(a)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Или как предложил [@MarianD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767043/255866), но с более правильным вариантов

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class App(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Тест'
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.radio_box_1 = QRadioButton('1', self)
        self.radio_box_2 = QRadioButton('2', self)
        button = QPushButton()
        button.setText('Вывод')
        button.clicked.connect(self.print_names)
        layout.addWidget(self.radio_box_1)
        layout.addWidget(self.radio_box_2)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.button_group = QButtonGroup()
        self.button_group.addButton(self.radio_box_1, 1)
        self.button_group.addButton(self.radio_box_2, 2)
        self.button_group.buttonClicked.connect(a.clear)
        self.button_group.buttonClicked.connect(a.append)

    def print_names(self):
        print(self.button_group.id(a[0]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = []
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
lambda:  a.clear()
```

используйте просто

```
a.clear
```

и вместо

```
lambda number_id: a.append(self.button_group.id(number_id))
```

просто

```
a.append(self.button_group.id)
```

Когда пишете имя функции или метода *без скобок*, это *объект* функции или метода - точно то, что вам нужно.

Comment: вы точно поняли что вы написали потому что я не совсем для начала `a.clear` это сразу ошибку выдаст как и  `a.append(self.button_group.id)`. 1 случай не сделает то что он по сути делает а именно очищает список, а второй из метода `self.button_group` в вашем случае выведет значение `QButtonGroup` и запишешь это в `a` и то без `lambda` у вас ничего не получиться

Comment: Что я написал, это безошибочно. Во башей программе синтаксическая ошибка и ни после ее поправки программа у меня не функциональная.

Comment: Нет, бы не привели рабочий код программы. `self.radio_box2` нужно исправить на `self.radio_box_2`. - Когда ошибка в `a.append(self.button_group.id)`, то эта самая ошибка будет и в `lambda number_id: a.append(self.button_group.id(number_id)))` - эти 2 комманды идентичны.

Comment: С кодом я согласен, я его  уже отредактировал, а вот с `a.append(self.button_group.id)`я не согласен т.к. вы вызываете в данном случае идентификатор самой кнопки а не сам `id` [http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#id]. по этому в данном случае `lambda` будет работать а ваш приведенный пример нет

Comment: Нет, я не вызываю *идентификатор самой кнопки* - я вызываю **функцию** - точно так, как вы вызываете, и в том-же самом контексте - как параметр метода `connect()`.

Comment: тогда выложите весь код вашей программы потому что я не особо понимаю как у вас оно должным образом работает

Comment: Это ваша программа, у меня нет "моего" варианта. Я не анализировал вашу программу, только ответил на ваш вопрос. А в этом контексте мой ответ правилен - когда ваша исходная программа работала, точно так будет работать после замены в моем ответе, когда не работала, точно так не будет работать после замены. (Может быть - какая-то ошибка вкралась при копировании из моего ответа?)

Comment: да так и есть потому что надо не как в вашем варианте заменять на `a.append(self.button_group.id)` а надо было заменить просто на `a.append` после чего в функции вызывать `print(self.button_group.id(a[0]))`

Comment: Хотя на много проще сделать как я уже описал в [своем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767065/255866) не используя лишний раз `self.button_group.buttonClicked.connect`

Comment: Я согласен. +1 :-)